# Retrieve characters before the '-' symbol in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I want to extract data from a column before the '-' symbol. I could do this easily with T-SQL but I am getting errors when I do the same in Azure Databricks.
I also want to be able to check the column if there is such a symbol and where it does not exist I don't want to extract the data.

In T-SQL I could write:

```
  SELECT EmailAddress
 ,SUBSTRING(emailaddress, 0, charindex('@', emailaddress, 0))
 FROM [dbo].[DimEmployee]
```

How do I get the same result in Databricks, please?

Comment: Can you share sample data along with the expected output please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To find records with ‘-’ symbol, you can use `pyspark.sql.Column.contains`

   ```
   Column.contains(other)
   ```

Contains the other element. Returns a boolean Column based on a string match.

2. ```
   regexp_extract_all function
   ```

Extracts the all strings in `str` that matches the regexp expression and corresponds to the regex group index.

```
regexp_extract_all(str, regexp [, idx] )
```

E.g.

```
SELECT regexp_extract_all('100-200, 300-400', '(\\d+)-(\\d+)', 1);
 [100, 300]
```

Refer - https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/regexp_extract_all.html#regexp_extract_all-function-databricks-sql